# Can't read data from Firebase Realtime database by issuing a GET request. Always returns null

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, http-get

Task is simple, but I couldn't find any solution though.

Here is the request I'm sending https://graf-24561-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/graf-24561-default-rtdb.json

Rules for reading and writing:

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": "now < 1651165200000",  // 2022-4-29
     ".write": "now < 1651165200000",  // 2022-4-29
   }
}
```

Data in code:

```
[
 {
  "name": "0002 М ( мрамор) 8м пленка с\/м\/20  DEKORON ",
  "price": 209.7
 },
 {
  "name": "0007 М ( мрамор) 8м пленка с\/м\/20  DEKORON ",
  "price": 209.7
 },
 {
  "name": "0008-2 А (дуб темный) 8м пленка с\/м \/20",
  "price": 232.84
 },
 {
  "name": "0008-3 А (темн.махагон) 8м пленка с\/м \/20 ",
  "price": 209.7
 }
 ]
```

[image: Screenshot of data in console]

[image: Trying to send request from postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `graf-24561-default-rtdb` that you see in the root of the JSON in the screenshot is the name of your database, and is **not** part of the data structure.

So to get the entire database, the URL would be:

```
https://graf-24561-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json
```

It may read a bit weird with that `.json` at the end, but *is* the correct syntax.